# Xamarin UI: Programmatically VS XAML

Tags: android, xamarin

recently I attended a talk on Xamarin and we were discouraged from using XAML for our UI design. I recently started mobile development and I would like to know which is the best way to design user-interfaces; doing it programmatically or using XAML?

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT 2017** - *With **XAMLC** (XAML-Compiler, read more [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/)) XAML is compiled to IL code at **build time** so no XAML parsing is involved at runtime anymore. In many cases this makes XAML as fast or very close to coding the UI in code-behind C#. With the latest improvements in XAML compilation, there is now **strongly typed** data binding (read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings)), which is faster and the data binding errors are caught during **build time**. Some errors in XAML are caught at **design time**, when you edit the XAML in the Visual Studio XAML editor*

I assume you're asking about Xamarin Forms.

It would be interesting if you could mention the reasons why you heard XAML is bad.

<del>The only reason I would think that someone could discourage you from using XAML is performance.</del>

<del>I came across some posts on Xamarin Forms talking about performance issues when using XAML for creating some of the UI with Xamarin Forms. 
But given than Xamarin Forms is an early technology, I guess these issues are temporary and will be fixed.</del>

I don't agree declarative UI (XAML) vs coded UI is just a matter of personal taste.

A declarative UI (today is XAML, tomorrow it can be something else) can be a better approach than doing the UI by code, for the following reasons:

- **It's coincise, it's impersonal**. Except few things, XAML looks the same for everyone. You can't say the same thing about actual code, which is more verbose, there are methods called, variables declared, etc.
- **It's more maintainable**. It's easier to read and modify than actual code.
- It helps with a **clear separation of concerns**, between the UI and logic. Same thing can be achieved without XAML, but just by using XAML you are closer to this goal.
- **Tooling friendly**. <del>Unfortunately Xamarin Forms today still doesn't have a previewer or designer, but this is supposed to change</del> There is a XAML Previewer baked-in in Visual Studio when you edit XAML, but it still doesn't work 100%. See more about Xamarin Forms XAML Previewer [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/live-xaml-previewing-with-the-xamarin-forms-previewer/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer?tabs=windows)

I am NOT saying XAML is perfect. But I think it's better than manually coding the UI. XAML uses same C# classes and properties of controls. The XAML syntax is the same with XML, because actually all XAML documents are valid XML documents. XAML is based on XML.

When someone says XAML is bad, I can't help thinking about HTML. Is HTML bad too? Is it better to create HTML elements in Javascript? Obviously it's not.
I know some will say you can't really compare XAML vs HTML because XAML is not as "native" as HTML, but aren't both just related to the presentation layer?

Xamarin (now Microsoft) has some nice introduction to XAML you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/).

I think developers with native iOS background have a strong inclination towards not using a declarative UI because that's how unfortunately native iOS development mostly works. You are forced to use code to implement different things which are not available in the designer and there's no native declarative UI markup language available(there's one but the format is not public and it's not meant to be directly modified).

You might know this by now but Xamarin Forms is not the only way to build apps with Xamarin. **Xamarin != Xamarin Forms**.
You can build your UI natively and still share the logic (ViewModels, services, etc). On Android, you can build your UI in the AXML. You will get as closer to the metal you can get with Xamarin with that. But you will need data-binding, so a framework like MvvmCross can help with that.

Comment: I would say it depends heavily on the target view. Something like RelativeLayout is definitely easier with code and a few other places as well where code is just quicker and cleaner. On the other hand intellisense makes it easier to create bindings in XAML and reduces errors due to wrong property names.

Comment: @SKall beside performance, I don't think think you should do it in code, it's not about which way is easier

Comment: XAML is fine for simple screens but for complex screen it just isn't enough.

Comment: Why wouldn't XAML be enough for complex screens? Complex screens need to be composed of smaller UI components.

Comment: A lot of assumptions here.

1. C#. C# is more verbose than XAML, because C# is verbose. Not all .Net languages are verbose.

2. Code-behind. Nothing forces code-defined UI to be "behind" anything. I believe you are assuming a specific anti-pattern where there is csharp code behind xaml. Nothing actually requires this "behind" structure.

3. "UI and logic". You are assuming UI has no logic, a limitation coming from XAML orthodoxy. The true distinction is separating non-UI logic and UI. This can be done by doing the non-ui logic in a project without access to views.

Comment: @CharlesRoddie 1. I didn't mention "verbose", you did. But any manual code is more verbose, there's syntax about using c-tors, calling methods, etc. Also, more problematic is not as impersonal like XAML, which is more simple and coincise 2. By code-behind UI, I also meant UI coded code. 3. I am referring to keeping UI logic in the UI layer. It's not a limitation, it's a very common (good) practice

Comment: Not using XAML doesn't imply non-declarative UI. Code can be declarative. C# has declarative parts and F# is very declarative. It also doesn't imply taking UI logic out of the UI layer (is that possible?), or mixing up UI and non-UI logic; you can separate these layers in code.

Comment: I personally find XAML a poor technology because it's full of magic strings which seem unrelated to the names of properties and classes, has a poor interface to code in that components need to be specially written to be XAML-friendly, and it is tied to a very verbose binding framework which predates generics and is therefore poorly typed.

Separating UI and non-UI layers is good but restricting the UI logic to trivial logic is artificial. The separation between UI and non-UI should be based on the purposes of the code and not the complexity of logic.

Comment: I rest my case. Despite the fact in another discussion (in the Xamarin Forms repository) I mentioned to you that XAML actually gives type checking through the XAMLCompiler, you keep saying same things. After all, it's fine, do whatever floats your boat, and like I said in my answer here, XAML is not perfect, but you should come up with some real arguments. I'm genuinely interested for a real discussion and sharing real experience.

Answer (score 3):

A very subjective question. Currently the state of Xamarin Forms XAML is similar to early Silverlight in terms of designer support. Similarly, in Visual Studio there has been a lack of Xaml Intellisence though if you use the latest version of Resharper it will provide Intellisense for it.

It can also be frustrating to debug as the command to load the Xaml can cause a crash if the Xaml is invalid. It is still debugable if you catch the exception right there but an error in custom code would be easier to find. Finally I have heard anecdotal evidence that in some cases the XAML is slower but I have not yet confirmed it.

Having said all that, I use XAML. It tends to be the defacto standard in development with languages that have XAML. I also suspect a Xamarin Forms XAML designer will come. Like the early days of Silverlight it is my belief that using XAML may not be the easiest today but it will likely be The best option to prepare your codebase for tomorrow. Once you code your UI you will have quite the task to switch to XAML when the tooling catches up.

But as I stated earlier, a subjective question.

Answer (score 2):

It has been my experience that each tool excels or under performs dependent on the context in which it is used. XAML in Xamarin.Forms is no different.

There are benefits and drawbacks to XAML and the ultimate decision of which to use where needs to be evaluated in a context aware setting.

In a recent project I use both. XAML for the majority of UIs and c# for things like dynamically generated forms. Below is a short and admittedly biased / incomplete list of pros and cons for figuring out which to use where.

**XAML Pros -**

- More clear separation of logic and UI
- Easier to read when UI implements styles, triggers, bindings
- Easier to add a second version of the UI for a different form factor (tablet/phone/watch)

**XAML Cons -**

- Harder to create a single implementation of custom page generation
- Intellisense is not currently supported without add ons or in SAP for Visual Studio
- It is not a complete set of XAML like you would get in a WPF project

The only thing I can say with certainty regarding this question is that a blanket statement condemning XAML in forms is non sense.

Comment: Today, XAML intellisense works pretty well in both Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio.

Comment: "It is not a complete set of XAML like you would get in a WPF project" that has nothing to do with deciding between using XAML in Xamarin Forms or coding the UI by code behind

Comment: For those coming from a WPF background expecting to be able to do the same things with XAML that they have done in the past it might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, and it's definitely just an opinion, I prefer to have a almost zero lines of code in a code behind class, where all the definitions of the view will residue in the Xaml file only.
This way, you'll **separate the UI from your code logic** and will probably have a much cleaner code eventually.

Having said that, Xamarin forms is still very young framework, and many times I've encountered in plugins that don't have support for Xaml, so I had to manipulate the UI using the code behind, but I do it only as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to do cross-platform WITHOUT using Xamarin.Forms. I feel like it's easier to create more expressive and pleasing UIs for each platform by using the native UI APIs. Again, as others have said, there is no "better" way to do this, it's all a matter of preference. I personally really enjoy using the iOS interface builder to create my views, and then wire them up to my custom view controllers. This is just what is most comfortable to me, and IMO allows me to create richer, more expressive UIs for my users.